# Отладка приложения удаляет другие приложения?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

Всем привет, я учу Xamarin.Forms. Пишу приложение под андроид и столкнулся с проблемой - я делаю отладку приложения через телефон, после отладки, приложение остается на телефоне, но если начать отладку другого приложения - первое пропадает с телефона, как этого избежать?

Comment: Дать им разные имена пакетов :)

Comment: @NewView, помогло, спасибо)